# DbSet and DbContext difference when removing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]

For the data model seen above, using the following Entity Framework statement:

```
Student student = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.ID == 1).Single();
foreach (var mapping in student.Student_CourseMappings.ToList())
{
    student.Student_CourseMappings.Remove(mapping);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

causes an error saying

> "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship,..."

But the following statement works:

```
Student student = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.ID == 1).Single();
foreach (var mapping in student.Student_CourseMappings.ToList())
{
    ctx.Student_CourseMappings.Remove(mapping);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Why does removing via the dbset not work but removing via the dbcontext work?

Comment: The first `Remove` makes it orphan(`UPDATE`) (which fails because it's a not null relationship), the second one removes it from the DB (`REMOVE`)

Answer (score 3):

In your first code you are not deleting the entities from your database, you're trying to break the relationship between the student and its courses, and the exception is because the FK in the relationship is required, so your orphan entities need to have a value in the FK property. In the second example, you are deleting the entities from the `DbSet<Student_CourseMapping>`  directly, which will delete the row from table as you are expecting.

Another thing I noticed now you need to know is in your first example you're not removing via `DbSet`, `Student_CourseMappings` is a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) in `Student` entity